# Unable to install new version of .NET Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a 64-bit Windows Service, written in C#. It was previously installed on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. We've made some changes to it, and are trying to deploy the new version to the same machine.

However, no matter what we do, the behavior we are seeing seems to indicate that the service that is running is the old version.

Here are the steps we've taken in an attempt to resolve this issue:

1. Uninstalled the service using INSTALLUTIL.
2. Used `SC DELETE` to verify that it is removed.
3. Deleted all files from the service's installation directory, as specified in the service's properties page in the Services snap-in.
4. Removed any registry entries associated with the service from `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet001\Services`.
5. Rebuilt the service and its dependencies with new version numbers.
6. Deployed the new version to the service's installation directory.
7. Reinstalled the service using INSTALLUTIL.
8. Verified that the Services snap-in and the registry are pointing to the correct location for the service executable.

Nonetheless, the behavior of the newly deployed service appears to be identical to the previous version. (Specifically, it is injecting messages into a queue in MSMQ, when that functionality was removed and can be verified to have been done so.)

We are positive that we are deploying the right version. This same behavior occurs even if we install the new version of the service from the Visual Studio project build folder (`bin\x64\release`).

Why is/would this be occurring? How do I resolve it? Are services cached somewhere and run from a cache when you install them? If so, where are they, and how do I properly clear them?

Or is this just something I've boned in the code?

Comment: "Seems to indicate" looks extremely vague. Do some logging/tracing. It's impossible for an application to run files that don't exist. BTW, did you do the first-step of restarting the pc?

Comment: did you change the existing code? or did you re-write the service from scratch..? I would make sure that all references are pointing to the correct path of the new .dll, also do a clean on the solution, rebuild, I would check the project file to make sure it's updated correctly etc.. try creating a new Service project and then copy paste the .cs files etc.. into the new project.. also check the .config files to make sure they are updated correctly too.. it's hard to know what you have or have not done when we are not sitting in front of what you are

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I chose "seems to indicate" very specifically because experience has taught me that what I think I see isn't always what I'm seeing. The service was modified so that it should only ever write to the message queue if an error occurs. However, it is writing thousands of informational messages to the queue, just as the previous version did. There is no code in the new version that writes informational messages to the queue.

Comment: @MethodMan The service was modified, not rewritten from scratch. I am fairly certain, at this point, that we've verified that all references are pointing to the correct path (as the steps in the question indicated). However, I'm willing to accept that I missed something somewhere, since something clearly isn't working.

Comment: @MethodMan The configuration files are correct, and I've double-checked the version numbers on the assemblies. They're correct.

Comment: use `notepad++ to edit / view the sln and the project file` can you reproduce this running / installing it locally..?

Comment: @MethodMan That's where it's occurring. (Locally, that is.)